# Sentry ignores --config path, but only for "start" command

Tags: django, config, sentry

I've installed Sentry into a virtualenv located at `/www/sentry/` and I have a config file `/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py`. I am able to run the following commands successfully:

- `$ sentry --config=/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py celery worker -B`
- `$ sentry --config=/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py upgrade`

I can even run `sentry --config=/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py shell` and then once in the Django shell, check that the `settings` module imported from `django.conf` has the custom settings I added in my `sentry.conf.py` file.

However, when I try to spin up the included Gunicorn server I get the following:

```
$ sentry --config=/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py start
Performing upgrade before service startup...
Loading help page organizations.md
Loading help page sampling.md
Loading help page tagging.md
Loading help page quotas.md
Loading help page teams_and_projects.md
Running service: 'http'
[2015-02-20 19:47:01 +0000] [19199] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-20 19:47:01 +0000] [19199] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9000 (19199)
[2015-02-20 19:47:01 +0000] [19199] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-02-20 19:47:01 +0000] [19219] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19219
[2015-02-20 19:47:01 +0000] [19219] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/services/http.py", line 34, in load
    import sentry.wsgi
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
    configure()
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/utils/runner.py", line 399, in configure
    initializer=initialize_app,
  File "/www/sentry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 89, in configure_app
    raise ValueError("Configuration file does not exist at %r" % (config_path,))
ValueError: Configuration file does not exist at '/www/.sentry/sentry.conf.py'
...etc...
```

I tried creating a `/www/.sentry/` directory, and then copying my config file into it and then the server loads without a problem:

```
$ mkdir /www/.sentry/
$ cp /www/sentry/sentry.conf.py /www/.sentry/sentry.conf.py
$ sentry --config=/www/sentry/sentry.conf.py start
Performing upgrade before service startup...
Loading help page organizations.md
Loading help page sampling.md
Loading help page tagging.md
Loading help page quotas.md
Loading help page teams_and_projects.md
Running service: 'http'
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19653] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19653] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9000 (19653)
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19653] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19673] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19673
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19674] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19674
[2015-02-20 19:50:12 +0000] [19675] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19675
```

This seems silly and unnecessary however. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I found this bug report:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/1438

This commit fixed it for me: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/commit/7629de1102973e4a3930487a3bf126a2f13c6850